# cuda - Is PyCuda slower than pure Cuda in the process of allocating memory and copying data to device?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I'm using a 1kB `.png` file (i.e a `2048x2048 numpy array`) to test my `PyCuda` program and it shows the program took about **1.57s** to allocate and copy the data to the device.

Is that normal to take such a long time?

I wonder whether `PyCuda` and `Cuda C` have performance difference in the allocating and memcpy procedure?

(As the kernel is still written in C when using PyCuda, the kernel executing time is about 0.17s so I feel it took too long to do the preparation.)

**Code to allocate and memcpy**

```
img_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(img.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(img_gpu, img)

result_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(result.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(result_gpu, result)

disX = np.array(disX).astype(np.int32)
disY = np.array(disY).astype(np.int32)

disX_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(disX.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(disX_gpu, disX)

disY_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(disY.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(disY_gpu, disY)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is neglible difference in performance between PyCUDA (in the way you are using it) and "native" CUDA.

The PyCUDA driver module is a very thin wrapper around the CUDA driver API, and you should expect them to perform the same. Context establishment and memory allocation are expensive operations, particularly on the Windows WDDM platform, and it would appear that all you are measuring is standard latency and setup overhead.